# A very basic SQL injection problem from my exam - will my "weird" solution work?

Tags: sql, security, code-injection

(I'm not a native english speaker, please excuse mistakes).

It was given some Java code which was in duty to build a simple SQL query. The task was to 
give String arguments to the two parameters `username` and `password` in order to delete the `user_table`.

NOTE: we did not get teached SQL code so don't worry about exact SQL syntax. It doesn't matter here.

I can't remember the exact code but it was very similar to this:

```
function(String username, String password)
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id =" + username + "AND pw =" + password;
    //invoke the SQL query with this String
}
```

Now the best solution here probably would have been:

```
username = "Oscar"
password = "123; DROP TABLE user_table"
```

But this is what I have written:

```
username = "Oscar; DROP TABLE user_table; 1=1"
password = "123"
```

The problem I see with my solution is that the very last SQL command would be `1=1 AND pw = 123` which is just a boolean expression floating around in the code doing nothing. It is not assigned to anything or serving as a condition for anything.

Would this result in a runtime error? And if yes, would the previous commands still be executed?

Comment: The point of this exercise is to learn to use parameters.  Learn to use parameters.

Comment: In SQL Server the entire batch wouldn't compile and nothing would have been executed. Generally a comment marker is used to comment out unwanted code

Comment: @GordonLinoff Do you mean calling the function with the parameters, i.e. function(username, password)? Please don't worry about this. It was not a beginners coding exam, it was all about security.

Comment: @MartinSmith ok, thank you. Then unfortunately I might not get alot of points for my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, this code:

```
String sql = 
    "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id =" + username + "AND pw =" + password;
```

Generates an invalid query:

- `id` and `pw` are presumably strings, so the values that are passed should be surrounded with single quotes
- there is a missing space before the `and` keyword

That should be:

```
String sql = 
    "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = '" + username + "' AND pw ='" + password + "'";
```

Now when it comes to the exercise, you can simply play with `pw` to add a `delete` statement after the `SELECT` (while still generating valid SQL for the `SELECT`). If the application code allows executing more than one query at a time, the second statement will be executed after the first.

So for example, this:

```
id: "foo"
pw: "bar'; DROP TABLE user_table; --"
```

Would be concatenated as:

```
SELECT * FROM user_table 
WHERE id = 'foo' AND pw ='bar'; DROP TABLE user_table; --'
```

Note that the final comment marker escapes the last quote. This is valid SQL, and would actually drop the table.

Morale: do use query parameters.

```
String sql = 
    "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = :id AND pw = :pwd";
```

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id =" + username + "AND pw =" + password;

username = "Oscar; DROP TABLE user_table; 1=1"

password = "123"

Now if you replace them manually will result in :

SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE id = Oscar; DROP TABLE user_table; 1=1 AND pw = 123

This will result in a SQL Syntax Error. If you want to be smart, you may add "--" at the end of username "Oscar; DROP TABLE user_table; 1=1--", which will comment the rest of the query and the injection will become valid.

Comment: Will this comment out the `1=1` as well? If not, I don't understand why this becomes valid now. There would still be a boolean expression floating around at the end doing nothing: 

Now it would just be `1=1` instead of `1=1 AND pw = 123`

Comment: My bad, add "--" before 1=1, and you can remove the "1=1"